# Flags to random guess "answers" declined by moderator

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, moderation

The gazillionth non-reproducible question was posted on Stack Overflow: [How do I select elements with contentEditable = true in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41678105/1529630)

Two answers appeared, one at least concluded that if the code in the question didn't work for the OP, it meant the browsers was IE6 or similar. IMO improbable, but whatever.

But the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41678324/1529630) just said the code worked fine and suggested some random guesses like refreshing the cache or using jQuery (I guess it's well-known that [jQuery is really great and does all things](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif)). So I flagged it as not an answer. A moderator quickly declined it.

A previous, similar case is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35328787/1529630), which just suggests using a normalize css file for a problem not related at all with the default user-agent stylesheet. Some moderator also declined the flag despite the [community consensus](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11345883) about removal.

A [third example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29751835/1529630):

> I ran the code [...] and I do not get any errors. [OP's code] There must be
>   something going on with your html anchor or http vs https possibly.

People are just posting random guesses completely unrelated to the problem, maybe because they didn't understand the problem, didn't care to reproduce it, or because it cannot be reproduced at all.

Some of these flags are (luckily not often) being declined by moderators. I don't like this.

Comment: Do note it takes 6 recommend delete or 3 20K+ deletes for there to be a consensus in the LQPQ.

Comment: Non-reproducibility aside, do you happen to know the answer to the question of how to select contenteditable elements? I'm not familiar with the attribute, or how its value is propagated if at all, so I'm not sure if it's entirely possible to do using conventional attribute selectors or if a pseudo-class is required - assuming such a use case is even reasonable.

Comment: @BoltClock I also wondered if setting the `contentEditable` property might not update the attribute, but it does (it's not a simple reflection, though): [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/editing.html#making-document-regions-editable-the-contenteditable-content-attribute). So it seems `[contenteditable="true"], [contenteditable=""]` is enough to select elements where content edition is enabled.

Comment: @Oriol: Which do you think is closer to the specced behavior, `[contenteditable="true"], [contenteditable=""]` or `:not([contenteditable="false"])`?

Comment: @BoltClock Selecting the descendants with this attribute-based approach is tricky because `:not([contenteditable="false"])` must be checked on all intermediate elements. In that case I would use `:read-write` (excluding `inputs`?)

Comment: `:not([contenteditable="false"])` will match non-editable elements which don't have any `contenteditable` nor are descendants of an element with a true `contenteditable`, and also it will match non-editable descendants of an element with `contenteditable="false"`. I wouldn't use that selector.

Comment: @Oriol: Ah yeah that's true. I think :read-write is the way to go, assuming contenteditable is properly implemented. I found at least two older questions on selecting contenteditable elements, but I'm not sure if either is a really good candidate for a canonical Q&A because [one's the result of an unrelated issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907525/how-do-you-style-contenteditable-in-firefox) and [the other has a "not" requirement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618967/content-editable-selector). (For obvious reasons, I'm not really a fan of the question being discussed here.)

Comment: @BoltClock And the second one is also about `user-select`, which is not inherited, but `user-select: none` affects the descendants, but implementations disagree with the spec draft and allow text selection to be reenabled, which is usually done on contenteditable elements via a `:read-write` selector in the default style sheet. This all makes things more confusing.

Comment: And therein lies the issue with trying to designate existing questions as canonical: most candidate questions have some other circumstances or requirements that make them too specific or otherwise meaningfully change the answer. Ironically, the question *here* would make a better canonical, if it wasn't for the "works for me" bit. Seth's answer is even accepted.

Answer (score 10):

> People are just posting random guesses

That makes them all *bad* answers.  Bad answers are still answers.  You shouldn't be flagging bad answers as NAA, because *they are still answers*.  When someone posts a bad answer *downvote* it.  That's the appropriate tool in place to deal with bad answers, not NAA flags.  The other tool at your disposal is to work to close unclear questions as quickly as possible, to prevent answers like this from even being able to be posted.

Comment: Well, I don't think things like "*There must be something going on with your html anchor or http vs https possibly*" are an answer at all. At most, it should be a comment instead.

Comment: @Oriol It's someone providing what they think is a description of how to solve the problem.  I agree entirely that it's a *bad* answer.  That doesn't make it *Not An Answer*.  By all means, downvote it.

Comment: I have been thinking for some minutes. Now I can see how "clear the cache" or "use a CSS reset" might be attempts to solve the problem. But I still can't manage to understand how "*There must be something going on with your [some technology]*" may be an attempt to solve the problem. I only see a tautology, someone asks a question because has a problem, and someone else repeats that since there is a problem, it means there is a problem somewhere.

Comment: @Oriol It suggests that there's a problem with the anchor, not just "some technology".  It's very much not tautological.  It's very vague, too vague to be useful in my eyes, but that's very different from a tautology.  It also contains more than just what you quoted.  I think it's a horrible answer, but it's clearly an attempt to answer the question.